# Jenkins - Uno Choice Plugin - can't get reference value

Tags: groovy, jenkins

I'm trying to use Uno-Choice Cascade Dynamic Choice Parameter plugin in Jenkins
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Uno+Choice+Plugin

The problem is that I can't access the value of the Referenced parameter.
I use the Groovy script that in the example but I can't get the value of States moreover it even 
doesn't return the ["Unknown state"] in the script as it return the one from the Fallback script

```
if (States.equals("Sao Paulo")) {
  return ["Barretos", "Sao Paulo", "Itu"]
} else {
  return ["Unknown state"]
}
```

I have Jenkins V1.593, Uno-Choice Plug-in V0.21

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same issue these last few days, and I got a solution here:
https://github.com/biouno/uno-choice-plugin/issues/16

Just update the version of uno-choice plugin to v0.22 from here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/biouno-developers/awNMG5QqYSk

And it should work. 
Best of luck.

Comment: There's actually no code, just download the hpi file from: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/biouno-developers/awNMG5QqYSk

and install it in your jenkins. Then the cascade parameter should work.